# Remote git branch changed to `main' but `master' in local submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule repo, added to my project when the remote called its main branch `master`. Now they renamed it to `main` and when I try to pull I get error:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

I could nuke the submodule and re-add it, I suppose. But is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one `.gitmodules` file in your repository, and it should have something like

```
 [submodule "foo"]
    path = bar
    url = https://github.com/baz/foo
    branch = master
```

If `branch` is not there, it defaults to `master`. You can add `branch = main`. If it's there, change it to `branch = main`. Commit the changes in `.gitmodules` and run `git submodule update --remote` to update the submodule.

As @torek mentioned, we can also use `git submodule set-branch -b main -- foo` to update the submodule's branch. Note that it's not `foo/`, just `foo` without the slash, for the submodule name.

Reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: `git submodule set-branch` can do the `.gitmodules`-file-edit for you. I'm not sure that using the command line is all that valuable myself (I run `vim ~/.gitconfig` directly myself after all) but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @torek Thanks. I didn't know `set-branch`. There are too many sub commands and options.

Comment: @ElpieKay I added an unrelated submodule with main branch called `main`, and don't see `branch = main` in `.gitmodules`.

Comment: @user3156459 You can edit `.gitmodules` and add `branch = main` in the section of the submodule. Also you could try `git submodule set-branch -b main -- $submodulename`. The branch could also be specified by `git add submodule -b main $submodulepath` in the beginning.

Comment: @ElpieKay My point was that cloning a repo as a submodule with main branch called `main` seems to default to `main` in `.gitmodules` if branch is not there.